# In a custom native UI component in Android, react-native 0.21.0, how can I pass properties from react-native to the setter methods in a ViewManager?

Tags: android, react-native

I followed the directions at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html that explain how to call a native component from React Native. However, the property setters in the ViewManager class are not called.

Answer (score 3):

One of the steps described in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html is this: 
"Properties that are to be reflected in JavaScript needs to be exposed as setter method annotated with @ReactProp (or @ReactPropGroup".

The import of ReactProp needs to be from the uimanager.annotations package, not from the uimanager package.

```
Correct import: import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;
```

Previously, I had used

```
Incorrect import: import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactProp
```

I found the solution here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5649